# Mapping of string to index value in networkx graph

Tags: python-3.x, list, indexing, mapping, networkx

Using Python Networkx, I am creating a graph of cities with their population.

```
#Graph Creation
my_Graph = nx.DiGraph()
my_Graph.add_nodes_from([
  ("S1", {"Population": 100}),
  ("S2", {"Population": 200}),
  ("S3", {"Population": 300})])

  my_Graph.add_edge("S1", "S2", capacity=50)
  my_Graph.add_edge("S2", "S1", capacity=30)
  my_Graph.add_edge("S2", "S3", capacity=70)
  my_Graph.add_edge("S3", "S2", capacity=50)
  my_Graph.add_edge("S1", "S3", capacity=55)
```

When I print the list of cities using:

```
    print("The cities are :", my_Graph.nodes)
```

my output is

> The cities are :['S1', 'S2', 'S3']

**I want a mapping function that maps the cities (nodes) to their indices in the network.**

Comment: Index in what? The original list that you passed to `add_nodes_from`? Networkx doesn't store the items in a list.

Comment: @DMalan yeah, I want the mapping of cities to their indexes in the graph.

Comment: Can't you look them up yourself in your original list?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to have a mapping function which dynamically maps the names of cities to their indices.

Comment: What is your desired output?  "Mapping" could refer to the drawing of the graph, or just matching up values.  Are you looking for the drawn NetworkX graph to display the city name (or population) as a label on each node?  Or are you looking for a list or dictionary of the index value of the node (0, 1, 2, etc.) and the name (or population) of the city that corresponds to that node?  Please clarify in your question.

Comment: @Andrew Thank you for the detailed response. At the moment what I want is that my mapping function maps the name of nodes (cities in this case) to their index names. I am not looking to draw nodes with their new names

Comment: So your desired output would be something like this: `{0: 'S1', 1: 'S2', 2: 'S3'}`?

Comment: @Andrew Sir, Initially when I use to extract edges of graph, the output was like [("S1","S2"), ("S1", "S3")...] and these are not integer indices. So I want to build an
an internal map that maps the string to the index value of that node for later use.

Comment: @Waqas Swati Please post an example of your desired output!  You are using many different terms for different things so it is very confusing to figure out what you actually want.

Comment: @Andrew I feel sorry for this trouble, suppose my graph has nodes from S1, S2 up to Sn, I want a function that changes the name of nodes from S1, S2.... to 1,2,3 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I think this might be what you're after.

Using the built-in [`convert_node_labels_to_integers`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers.html#networkx.relabel.convert_node_labels_to_integers), you can do the following (assuming you want to start the labeling at 1 as indicated in your comments):

```py
my_Graph = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(my_Graph, first_label = 1)

my_Graph.nodes()
>>>[1, 2, 3]

my_Graph.edges()
>>>[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 2)]
```

Nodes are converted to integers and the edges are kept between the correct nodes with the updated names.  The attributes of the nodes and edges are maintained as well if you need them.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I cannot vote at the moment but I appreciate your efforts